weird python sqlalchemy enviroment problem
So im using a python enviroment for my project (as you can notice in the screenshot)

When i try to run my script, I get that sqlalchemy is not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ftiendahelp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

However when i run pip list using same enviroment i have this:
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2024.8.30
charset-normalizer 3.4.0
greenlet           3.1.1
idna               3.10
pip                24.0
PyMySQL            1.1.1
requests           2.32.3
schedule           1.2.2
setuptools         65.5.0
SQLAlchemy         2.0.36
typing_extensions  4.12.2
urllib3            2.2.3

According to my knowledge; It means sqlalchemy is correctly instaled on the enviroment.
My idea was to be sure about what i was doing was "to run which python from the enviroment" and i will be able to see if my project is actually using python from the enviroment or somewhere else output was:
/root/ftiendahelp/timer/bin/python

so unless im wrong im using python from the enviroment which has sqlalchemy already installed so i check my imports again:
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,BigInteger, create_engine,delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base
from contextlib import contextmanager
import requests,schedule,time

my final idea was to check it by trying install again so it will tell me the path of where the files were being taken
(timer) root@v321517364:~/ftiendahelp# pip install pymysql
Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in ./timer/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.1.1)

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(timer) root@v321517364:~/ftiendahelp# pip install sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in ./timer/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.0.36)

but once again i get module not found, can anynone please tell me if im maybe missing something?

How are you running your script?
